# How to pass parameter of type UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>

Tags: ios, swift

I have to use `CFDictionaryCreate` method in Swift([documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFDictionaryCreate)).

I am having a hard time to initialize the input parameters correctly in order to pass parameters(keys and values) of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>`.

Here is my code:

```
    var font_name: CFStringRef! = CFStringCreateWithCString(nil, "Courier", kCFStringEncodingASCII)
    var font: CTFontRef! = CTFontCreateWithName(font_name, 25.0, nil)
    var keys: [UnsafePointer<Void>] = ???? // how to intialize with "kCTFontAttributeName"
    var values: [UnsafePointer<Void>] = ???? // how to intialize with "font" variable
    var keyCallBacks = kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks
    var valueCallBacks = kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks
    var font_attributes: CFDictionaryRef! = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,   &keys, &values, sizeofValue(keys), &keyCallBacks, &valueCallBacks)
    var attr_string: CFAttributedStringRef! = CFAttributedStringCreate(nil, "hello", font_attributes)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot use a Swift dictionary instead? A Swift `[NSString : AnyObject]` dictionary is automatically bridged to `NSDictionary` (and vice versa), and `NSDictionary` is toll-free bridged with `CFDictionary`. – Perhaps you should show your concrete case.

Comment: @MartinR,  I have added the code. I am not sure if I can use NSDictionary in the above code. Can you help me out here?

Comment: What do you need the `font_attributes` dictionary for?

Comment: I need font_attributes to create following  ........         var attr_string: CFAttributedStringRef! = CFAttributedStringCreate(nil, "hello", font_attributes)............Added code in question too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use a Swift dictionary of type `[ NSString : AnyObject ]`, which is automatically bridged to `NSDictionary` or
`CFDictionary`. Note that you don't need `CFStringRef` either.

```
let font = CTFontCreateWithName("Courier", 25.0, nil)
let attributes : [ NSString : AnyObject ] = [ kCTFontAttributeName : font ]
let attrString = CFAttributedStringCreate(nil, "Hello", attributes)
```

Alternatively,

```
let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello", attributes: attributes)
```

because `NSAttributedString` is toll-free bridged with
`CFAttributedString`.

---

Just for the sake of completeness, here is how you could use
`CFDictionaryCreate()`:

```
let font = CTFontCreateWithName("Courier", 25.0, nil)
var keys = [ unsafeAddressOf(kCTFontAttributeName) ]
var values = [ unsafeAddressOf(font) ]
var keyCallbacks = kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks
var valueCallbacks = kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks
let attributes = CFDictionaryCreate(nil, &keys, &values, 1, &keyCallbacks, &valueCallbacks)
let attrString = CFAttributedStringCreate(nil, "Hello", attributes)
```

Comment: Thanks Genius!  It worked great. Just to increase my knowledge, any idea how to deal with parameters of  type UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>. Thanks again :)